# Cannot Access MQ Manager using MQServer environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have Windows Server 7 x64 on my pc and IBM MQ Client 9.0.0.8. I am trying to access queue manager on another server through a .net application. When I set specific properties and try to access qm as follows:

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable(); 
props.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "x"); 
props.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "y"); 
props.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, dddd); 
props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT); 
qManager = new MQQueueManager("z");
```

it is working great. But when I try to set the MQSERVER environment variable with the corresponding mq server settings in `channelName/TCP/server-address(port)` format (using exactly the same values used in code above), it's not.Is it user rights issue? What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Mq client includes some samples.   Can you try `amqscnxc z` and see if it connects with your ENV variable settings.

Comment: MQSERVER environment variable values can be over-ridden by an application providing the values directly in the application. Is it possible the application is doing that? Please update your question with the reason code you received and any error in the client side AMQERR01.LOG

Comment: In your sample you have `qManager = new MQQueueManager("z");` without the properties hash as a 2nd parameter, absent `MQEvironment` settings this would pick up `MQSERVER` env settings over all other possible settings (CCDT env or mqclient.ini for example).